# offloading data to another db-table and cache

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, caching

I have an online store, our products come from a 4 table join.
I want to move away from these joins for the following reasons:

1. too expensive on the database.
2. when I need to query data, I want to use simpler queries.

I am thinking of offloading the data into a simpler form into another DB and table.
Then, in addition, cache that data coming from the new table.

This gives me:

1. Good performance
2. simpler querying when I need to perform on the fly lookups using a DB client.

Can anyone weigh in on whether or not this is a good approach?
Am I overdoing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach, what you are doing is denormalizing and this should only be done as a last resort if you really need to increase performance in your system. I've worked on websites with over 10 million views per month and even on those sites it was only necessary for some specific use cases.

MySQL joins are very fast, and joining on 4 tables is nothing, I've written queries joining to 15 tables that ran in less than 0.001s, if your indexes are done right the difference won't be noticeable.

What you're doing is both [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and query writing laziness, unless your online store gets hundreds of thousands (or even millions) of visits every day you are not focusing on the right things, data integrity and consistency is way more important.

Comment: So, you understand my problem? if so, what is a solution?

Comment: Well I don't know your database structure, but if it's fine you shouldn't need to worry about performance, if queries are slow run "explain" on them instead and check if there are missing indexes on some fields.